# Resonance structure of acetate

Tags: chemfig

I need to draw a scheme to show the stabilization of the acetate ion by resonance and I'm going crazy :-(
I started using chemfig not so long ago and it seems that I need a lot more practice! In the meanwhile, can anybody help me solve the problem?
I would like something like this [image]

But I failed already by adding the first arrow :-(

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{R-C(=[1]{@{a1}\lewis{2:0:,O}})[@{db}](-[7]{\lewis{0:4:6:,{\chemabove{O}{\scriptstyle\hspace{3mm}\ominus}}}})}
\arrow{<->}
\chemfig{R-C(=[1]{\lewis{2:0:,O}})(-[7]{\lewis{0:4:6:,{\chemabove{O}{\scriptstyle\hspace{3mm}\ominus}}}})}
\arrow{<->}
\chemfig{R-C(=[1]{\lewis{2:0:,O}})(-[7]{\lewis{0:4:6:,{\chemabove{O}{\scriptstyle\hspace{3mm}\ominus}}}})}
\schemestop
\chemmove{\draw(db).. controls +(100:5mm) and +(145:5mm).. (a1);}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Probably something like this?

[image: Acetate resonance structures]

```
\documentclass[
    crop,
    border=5,
    tikz=true,
    multi={page},
    12pt
]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
    modules = all,
}
\usepackage{chemfig}
    \setchemfig{
        angle increment = 15,
        atom sep = \bndlen,
        bond offset = 0.5pt,
        double bond sep = 3pt,
        compound sep = 5.0em,
        arrow coeff = 1,
        arrow offset = 12pt,
        scheme debug = false,
        bond join = true,
        chemfig style={line width=\lnwidth},
        arrow style={line width=\lnwidth},
    }

\newcommand{\bndlen}{2.0em}
\newcommand{\lnwidth}{0.7pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{page}
\schemestart
    \chemleft{[}
    \subscheme{
        \chemfig{
            CH_3
            -C
            (-[::-45]\lewis{1:5:7:,O}\rlap{\color{purple}{${\ }^-$}})
            =[@{b1}::45]@{o1}\lewis{1:3:,O}
        }
        \arrow{<->}
        \chemfig{
            CH_3
            -C\rlap{\color{teal}{${}^+$}}
            (-[@{b2}::-45]\lewis{1:5:7:,O}@{o2}\rlap{\color{purple}{${\ }^-$}})
            -[::45]\lewis{1:3:7:,O}\rlap{\color{purple}{${\ }^-$}}
        }
        \arrow{<->}
        \chemfig{
            CH_3
            -C
            (=[::-45]\lewis{5:7:,O})
            -[::45]\lewis{1:3:7:,O}\rlap{\color{purple}{${\ }^-$}}
        }
        \chemmove{
            \draw[shorten <=3pt,shorten >=1pt,purple](b1)..controls +(-15:10mm) and +(-30:5mm)..(o1);
            \draw[shorten <=3pt,shorten >=1pt,purple](o2)..controls +(90:5mm) and +(45:5mm)..(b2);
        }
    }
    \chemright{]}
\schemestop
\end{page}

\end{document}
```

Also, if you are after a picture-perfect replica, note that the font family used in your illustration is most likely proprietary [ITC New Baskerville](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/new-baskerville/).
In order to use it, you have to obtain the font or use a free alternative from [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/); it would be easier to compile with XeLaTeX at this point.

Comment: Both your and leandris answers are great. May I suggest a tiny change? If you add `\tikzset{andselisk/.style={out=-70,in=-100,relative,looseness=2}}`, you could draw the bent arrows with `\draw[andselisk,shorten <=3pt,shorten >=1pt,purple](b1) to (o1);`. The combination of `in`, `out` and `relative` would spare the user from adding different control points for every annotation.

Answer (score 6):

Here are two possible version of the first reaction step with two variants of the arrow. The exact parameters might however still need some fine tuning.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{R-C(=[@{db}1]{@{a1}\lewis{2:0:,O}})(-[7]{\lewis{0:4:6:,{\chemabove{O}{\scriptstyle\hspace{3mm}\ominus}}}})}
\schemestop
\chemmove{\draw(db).. controls +(100:5mm) and +(145:5mm).. (a1);}

\vspace{1.5cm}

\schemestart
\chemfig{R-C(=[@{db}1]{@{a1}\lewis{2:0:,O}})(-[7]{\lewis{0:4:6:,{\chemabove{O}{\scriptstyle\hspace{3mm}\ominus}}}})}
\schemestop
\chemmove{\draw[shorten <=4pt,shorten >=4pt](db).. controls +(10:5mm) and +(-10:10mm).. (a1);}
\end{document}
```

With color:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{R-C(=[@{db}1]{@{a1}\lewis{2:0:,O}})(-[7]{\lewis{0:4:6:,{\chemabove{O}{\scriptstyle\hspace{3mm}\color{red}\ominus}}}})}
\schemestop
\chemmove{\draw[shorten <=4pt,shorten >=4pt, color=red](db).. controls +(10:5mm) and +(-10:10mm).. (a1);}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please can you put, if possible, also the colours that is, IMHO, more very nice? +1 now.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I added a second MWE showing how to change the color of the charge symbol as well as of the curved arrow.

Comment: I hope I didn't bother you. With the colors it certainly looks more pleasant. Thank you for your patience. I have seen that your code with color has this error: `Package pgf Error: No shape named a1 is known. [...controls +(10:5mm) and +(-10:10mm).. (a1);}]`

Comment: @Sebastiano Indeed. I think curly brackets around `@{a1}\lewis{2:0:,O}` should be removed.

Comment: @andselisk I will wait for the answer of the very good user leandriis. My best regards.